# Databricks- Convert Python DataFrame to Scala DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a dataframe in python, df, that i want to pass to be able to use in % scala.

I have tried -

```
%python
pyDf.createOrReplaceTempView("testDF") // error message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not too difficult. I am sharing a sample code pls try. It's working in Pycharm or databricks.

from pyspark.sql import *

import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("testing").getOrCreate()

data = [['venu', 50], ['renu', 45], ['anu', 54],['bhanu',14]]

## Create the pandas DataFrame

pdf= pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

print(pdf)

## Python Pands convert to Spark Dataframe.

sparkDF=spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

sparkDF.printSchema()

sparkDF.show()

[image]

Comment: How can you access python object from scala ?

Answer (score 1):

Just query it with `spark.sql`:

```scala
val scalaDf = spark.sql("select * from testDF")
```